# ChromeCast Android mute/unmute button working reverse with iOS

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In ExpandedControllerView the mute/unmute button is working reversely in android sample app compared to iOS sample.Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior on the Android is correct; the icon should show the action if one taps on the icon so, for example, when a video is playing, it should show the pause icon so if the behavior on iOS is not the same, please open a ticket for that to be addressed [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for the information . Issue is raised on google cast SDK.

Comment: Link for issue in cast sdk forum https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1058